# How to draw on bitmap using Skiasharp and Google Cloud Vision annotation's bounding poly?

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-cloud-vision, skiasharp

I'm trying to draw a rectangular highlight object around Google Cloud Vision's annotations via the Skiasharp library (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/) in Xamarin Forms. My code currently looks like this:

```
        private SKBitmap HighlightWord(byte[] bytes, Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.EntityAnnotation entityAnnotation)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);

        SKBitmap bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(ms);
        var canvas = new SKCanvas(bitmap);

        SKPaint skPaint = new SKPaint { Color = new SkiaSharp.SKColor(255, 255, 0, 50) };
        SKPoint[] points = entityAnnotation.BoundingPoly.Vertices.Select((vertex) => new SKPoint(vertex.X, vertex.Y)).ToArray();
        canvas.DrawRect((points[0].X + points[1].X)/2, (points[1].Y + points[2].Y) / 2, points[1].X - points[0].X, points[3].Y - points[0].Y, skPaint);

        return bitmap;
    }
```

What this code tries to do is to convert the bounding poly vertecies to Skiasharp points (they do return coordinates which appear to be correct) and then use these vertexes to draw a rectange around the annotation. I believe that the X and Y coordinates (the first to parameters) are supposed to be in the centre of the rectangle so I am adding the minimum and maximum values of the respective points of the rectangle and dividing it by two. Then I assign the width and height (the final two parameters) to the value when substracting the edges of the rectangle. **The problem that I encounter after running this code is that the resulting rectangles are all over the place- their position and size are both incorrect.** Based on the coordinates that I obtain from the vertex array: 1(277,217); 2(407,219); 3(407,244); 4(277,244) I can deduce which point is which in the figure but from there on I really just guessed which approach I should take using this library so my method could be entirely wrong. If you know how to fix this code or where I can find a similar project from which I can see how to accomplish this, I would really appriciate your help.
Edit:
Scan One: 
Point 0(122,282); Point 1 (202,298); Point 2(202,298); Point 3(121,299)
Result:[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FQZZ.png)

Comment: first, are you sure that the coordinate system used by Google and Skia match?  This is the kind of problem where using a pencil and some graph paper first might be a good idea.

Comment: Hello Jason, thank you for your reply again. I've tested them several times now because I also assumed that they were the source of error. I tried checking whether they were faulty by creating a simple rectange using the following parameters(10,10,300,100) and it also appears to be inverted. By inverted I mean that for some reason the rectangle's width should be it's height and vice versa. I swapped their values and now the size appears to be correct but the position is still off.

Comment: can you post the sample image you are passing to Google and the coordinates that it is returning?

Comment: I  just edited the post to include that information. Note that I also swapped the X and Y coordinates for the position as well and the result got a little closer to what is expected.

Comment: that is the actual image you're sending to Google?  Or is that a picture of the screen showing the image?  If it's the second case, that is useless.  And what in that image is Google supposed to be identifying?

Comment: It's the picture I am sending to Google- I freeze the camera frame and then send it for recognition. The annotation i am trying to highlight are the words in the blue box but all of the text in the frame is identified.

Comment: instead of using DrawRect, have you tried just directly drawing lines between the 4 points returned by Google?

Comment: I tried that but the result is still off target. I believe that this may be a result of the two images having a different size. Do you know how I can get the Cloud Vision image's size?

Comment: load it into a SKBitmap and check it's dimensions?